# R function for randomly removing one data point at a time from each category?

Tags: r, function, random, analysis

I am trying to analyze how estimating percent cover of a reef changes as the number of points used to analyze the reef changes. My actual dataset consists of 150 photos each with 50 points. The idea is to have R estimate percent cover with all those points and then remove 1 point from each photo and reanalyze, then remove another point and reanalyze etc.

Any help in how I can write or find or where I can look for a function like this is welcome as I am very new to all this! Below is a sample dataset with just 3 plots and 5 points per plot. So as mentioned the idea is to analyze with all points, then **randomly** remove one point from **each** plot, reanalyze and repeat. Basically this sample the first analysis would be 15 points, the next analysis would be a total of 12 plots etc.

Sample dataset:

```
Plot ID
1    S
1    S
1    S
1    T
1    T
2    S
2    C
2    C
2    SP
2    S
3    S
3    T
3    T
3    C
3    T
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### base R

```r
set.seed(42)
dat[ave(rep(TRUE, nrow(dat)), dat$Plot, 
        FUN = function(z) length(z) > 1 & !seq_along(z) %in% sample(length(z), 1)),]
#    Plot ID
# 2     1  S
# 3     1  S
# 4     1  T
# 5     1  T
# 6     2  S
# 7     2  C
# 8     2  C
# 9     2 SP
# 12    3  T
# 13    3  T
# 14    3  C
# 15    3  T
```

I added the logic to ensure a minimum size of 1 (`length(z) > 1`), you might want to bump this up if you have different needs, or remove that condition if you don't care about removing a `Plot` when it has only one row.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
dat %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  sample_n(n() - 1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#     Plot ID   
#    <int> <chr>
#  1     1 S    
#  2     1 T    
#  3     1 T    
#  4     1 S    
#  5     2 C    
#  6     2 SP   
#  7     2 S    
#  8     2 C    
#  9     3 S    
# 10     3 C    
# 11     3 T    
# 12     3 T
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there something I can add so on the dplyr so that it keeps removing a point randomly. For example: right now we started with 5 points per plot and it removed one so there was 4 per plot. Could it do it 2 more times automatically so that we get to 2 per plot?

also why did you set the set.seed() to 42?

Comment: Use a `for` loop or something similar if you want to repeat something. `dplyr` isn't set up for iterating on things in that fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R function with `tapply/sample`.
Its arguments are the data.frame and the grouping column.

```
sample_rows <- function(data, group){
  group <- as.character(substitute(group))
  tapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), data[[group]], \(x) sample(x, 1))
}

set.seed(2021)

i <- sample_rows(df1, Plot)
df2 <- df1[-i, ]
nrow(df2)
#[1] 12

i <- sample_rows(df2, Plot)
df2 <- df2[-i, ]
nrow(df2)
#[1] 9
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ID = c("S", "S", "S", "T", "T", "S", "C", 
"C", "SP", "S", "S", "T", "T", "C", "T")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```